# How to get current shift by current Time from Mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my table : **shift_master**

```
shift(varchar)     | start_time(varchar) | end_time(varchar)    
Morning            | 06:00 AM            | 02:00 PM    
AfterNoon          | 02:00 PM            | 10:00 PM    
Evening            | 10:00 PM            | 06:00 AM
```

I need one query in which I will pass the current time and it will give the record of shift which is currently going on.

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Thanks @Giorgos Betsos

Comment: Storing time values as `varchar` is not such a good idea. It would make things a lot simple to use MySQL's native `TIME` data type instead.

Comment: It turns out that the worse part in the way the shifts are represented is the fact that `Evening` spans multiple days. IMHO it would be a lot simpler to get the result you want had you broken the `Evening` shift *in two separate records*, i.e. `10:00 PM - 12:00 PM` and `00:00 AM - 06:00 AM`.

Answer (score 0):

First Change your datatype for start_time and end_time to timestamp and enter time in its format and then

```
SELECT shift FROM shift_master WHERE start_time <= NOW() AND end_time > NOW();
```

Its difficult to compare the time stored as varchar with current_time. If possible, then do as described above, it will simplify your work.

Comment: Sorry @Vrajesh Doshi, our requirement is to store in 'H:I A' formate. So in timestamp I can not store data in this formate.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this

```
SELECT shift FROM shift_master WHERE TIME(NOW()) BETWEEN TIME(STR_TO_DATE(start_time,'%h:%i %p')) AND TIME(STR_TO_DATE(end_time,'%h:%i %p'))
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. It is true when current time is less then 22:00:00. But my current time is 23:00:00 then Result should be 'Evening'. But in your query I got nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
set @now_time = UNIX_TIMESTAMP( now() ) % 86400;

SELECT shift
FROM ( SELECT shift, UNIX_TIMESTAMP( STR_TO_DATE(start_time,'%h:%i %p') ) % 86400 as start, UNIX_TIMESTAMP( STR_TO_DATE(end_time,'%h:%i %p') ) % 86400 as end
FROM shift_master ) M
WHERE ( start < end AND @now_time BETWEEN start AND end - 1 ) OR
( start > end AND ( @now_time > start or @now_time < end ) )
```

Comment: @PHPDev what is the output of this query for you?

Comment: @PHPDev can you give me exported sql from your current table?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT shift
FROM shift_master
WHERE (start_time < end_time and (start_time <= time(now()) and end_time > time(now())))
OR (start_time > end_time and (start_time <= time(now()) or end_time > time(now())))
```